# Fordward xclock graphical interface

Tags: solaris, xming

I have computer A in which I run "xclock" program. I want to forward it's graphical interface to my pc, not directly but through computer B. Is it possible? I'm running xming on my pc.

Resuming: A runs xclock > A forwards to B > B forwards to my PC. Is it possible?